# Как толкать объекты игроком сделаным через Character controller. Игрок сфера

Tags: unity3d, controller

Игрок реализован через Character controller с помощью Move добавление rb на игрока не помогло как и переделка кода на движение через SimpleMove. Хочется реализовать возможность сдвигать объекты толчком сферы(игрока). Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

> Science!

Можешь просто для объектов привязать RigidBody, и настроить им вес такой, при котором игрок с (необходимой) лëгкостью сдвигает эти предметы

Comment: А вот нет, даже если у объекта есть коллайдер и RigidBody, то его не получается сдвинуть даже если у игрока есть rb. Так как игрок реализован на Character controller то передвигается не посредством физики(rb) а посредством смешения(transform.position). Но отмечу что игрок сделанный на rb двигает объекты, только по проекту нужно именно Character controller.

Comment: Без Rigidody не подвинуть объекты с Rigidody (если не учитывать костыли)

Comment: Ну вот я когда тестил мой игрок с rb не мог сдвинуть предмет с rb так как его двигал не addforce, а Move от Character controller. И так как к игроку небыло приложено сил он не может сдвинуть объект.